# Application theme dose't change using Theme in Editor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, styles, themes, app-themes

Hi I'm new to Android and I just want to change my App theme using "Theme in Editor" in Android Studio the Theme is to change preview but when I run application I don't see any conversion and when I want to edit Apptheme attribute of style it doesn't recognize for example Holo theme.

Comment: "Theme in Editor" is just as it says, a way to change the theme shown in the layout editor. To change the app theme, read [Customize the default theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#CustomizeTheme)

Answer (score 3):

Go to **AndroidManifest.xml**.In Application Tag press **CTR+ click** on **android:theme="@style/AppTheme**" It open the style.xml then change your theme as you want in style name="AppTheme" parent="**Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**">

Answer (score 0):

Change android:theme="@style/AppTheme" to  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" in your manifest file .